# jquery return array from function ( XMLHttpRequest )

Tags: jquery

i try to return an array from a function:

```
function test (CAR,DATE) {
some XMLHttp Request <- Works
var arrayTrip = JSON.parse(xhrTrip.response); <- Works
console.log(arrayTrip); <- Works
return arrayTrip; <- unsure

}
var test = new myTest(input,time); <- unsure
console.log(test); <- not the array as in console.log(arrayTrip)
```

But this is not working.
Is there any way to receive the array?

Comment: 1. Please update with more detail of your code instead of "some XMLHTTP"; 2. What did console print?

Comment: I would change `var test = new myTest(input,time); <- unsure` to `var result = test(input,time); <- unsure`. no need for `new` and the function is called `test` and not `myTest`